# yii2 How to remove unused query parameters from url

Tags: javascript, php, url, parameters, yii

I have Kartik gridView and custom filter. After gridfilter in my browser i got URL like

```
localhost:20024/consignment?fid=&post_code=&pud2_mrn=&pud2_status=PUDP&pud_status=&pud2_remaining_date=&mrn=&mrn_status=&ioss_number=&declaration_type=&status=&entry_at=&exit_at=&created_at=
```

Is there a way to remove unfilled parameters from url inside YII instead javascript?
Or can anybody provide full example of javascript to achieve the goal.

Comment: You may want to look at https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/pull/16848/. I don't think there is anything like that merged in framework, but you could patch it.

Comment: @rob006 Thank you for your response, but this doesn't fit my need. First of all because i am using Kartik and second i cant rewrite vendor files

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Kartik is using default scripts from Yii 2 to handle filtering.

Comment: @rob006 it is still in vendor, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Copy `vendor/yiisoft/yii2/yii.gridView.js` somewhere under `web` directory (e.g. `web/js` and add this line:

```
$.each(data, function (name, value) { if (value[0].length === 0) data[name] = null; });
```

prior this line in `applyFilter` method:

```
var pos = settings.filterUrl.indexOf('?');
```

Then add this to `web.conf` (update paths if you used different place for this js file):

```
'assetManager' => [
    'bundles' => [
        'yii\grid\GridViewAsset' => [
            'sourcePath' => '@webroot/js',
            'basePath' => '@webroot/js',
            'baseUrl' => 'vendor/js',
        ],
    ],
],
```

This was you are not modifying anything in the `vendor` folder.